# Удаление строк из датафрейма, если значение встречается меньше или больше, чем N раз

Tags: python, pandas

Как удалить строки из df, если значение встречается меньше 3 или больше 3 раз в колонке match_id

| match_id | player | win |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 1 | 0 |
| 111 | 2 | 0 |
| 111 | 3 | 0 |
| 112 | 1 | 1 |
| 112 | 2 | 1 |
| 113 | 1 | 0 |
| 113 | 2 | 0 |
| 113 | 3 | 0 |
| 113 | 4 | 0 |
| 113 | 5 | 0 |
| 113 | 6 | 0 |

Должно остаться только:

| match_id | player | win |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 1 | 0 |
| 111 | 2 | 0 |
| 111 | 3 | 0 |

помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Группируем по `match_id`, считаем каждую группу через `transform('count')`, делаем булев массив c `.eq(3)` и отбираем нужные строки через `df[булев массив]`

```
df = df[df.match_id.groupby(df.match_id).transform('count').eq(3)]
```

```
   match_id  player  win
0       111       1    0
1       111       2    0
2       111       3    0
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать этим способом:

```
match_id_counts = df['match_id'].value_counts()
valid_match_ids = match_id_counts[match_id_counts == 3].index
filtered_df = df[df['match_id'].isin(valid_match_ids)]
```

В этом варианте сначала были посчитаны повторения в столбце, затем отобраны те значения, которые повторялись ровно 3 раза, а затем датафрейм был отфильтрован по этим значениям.